# How to use the result of GROUP_CONCAT in an RLIKE query?

Tags: mysql

Given a table `keywords` which contains some keywords for searching, and another table `titles` of which title to search. I tried `GROUP_CONCAT` all words in `keyword` and fed the result (`'w1|w2|w3|w4'`) in a `RLIKE` query as following:

```
select title from titles where title rlike
(select group_concat(distinct word separator '|') from keywords) as keyword;
```

But the statement violated the SQL syntax. How could I fix the statement (assuming `full-text search` is unavailable)?

Comment: Please show us the exact error you are getting from MySQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That seems like a very odd thing to do.  Why not just use `exists`?

```
select t.title
from titles t
where exists (select 1
              from keywords kw
              where t.title rlike kw.word
             );
```